# How to Stop Windows Media Center remote from controlling XBox 360 *AND* XBMC?

Tags: windows-media-center, xbox360, kodi

I have an XBMC PC (Windows 7) setup to my TV, along with an XBox 360. As to be expected the remote control sends signals to both the Xbox and XBMC PC, which is problematic as I will sometimes go back and forth between the two and they can each end up in very weird states, e.g. XBMC ending up deep inside settings, because of the buttons I was pressing while using the 360.

Has anyone come up with some clever ideas so only one system is being controlled at a time. For instance, maybe the PC can detect when it is being displayed and therefore only accept commands when it is displayed.

Note: Pressing the WMC button on the remote causes the app to run on the 360 and for the app to start in the windows 7 PC, but my real issue is that pressing the other buttons will also control both XBMC and the 360, e.g. pressing the back button will send a signal to both the XBMC and 360 to "go back".